# having trouble finding the sum of my array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, int

```
        while (file.hasNext()) {
        if (file.hasNextInt()) {
            int readMidGrades = file.nextInt();
            int readFinalGrades = file.nextInt();

            int[] midterms = {readMidGrades};
            int[] finals = {readFinalGrades};




            double sum = 0;

            for(int i=0; i<midterms.length; i++) {
                sum += midterms[i];
            }
            double average=(sum/midterms.length);
            System.out.print(average);
```

So, i am trying to find the sum of my array. I have made two int arrays, i received the numbers from a file. When try to get the sum it prints out the numbers but does not sum them. I am writing it exactly how my textbook says and even other ways i have found on here. I would like to keep the for loop that I have. Is this happening because it is saving the numbers as a string??

Comment: The arrays always have length of 1, so you're not really "summing" anything. You might as well have written `average = readMidGrades`.

Answer (score 0):

For now you have two arrays of one element, both reinitialize every time in your loop (also I think there are missing parenthesis).

Consider using of *ArrayList* for *readMidGrades* and *readFinalGrades* values storage. So your code should look like that:

```
List<Integer> midterms = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> finals = new ArrayList<>();
while (file.hasNext()) {
  if (file.hasNextInt()) {
      int readMidGrades = file.nextInt();
      int readFinalGrades = file.nextInt();

      midterms.add(readMidGrades);
      finals.add(readFinalGrades);
  }
}


double sum = 0;

for(int i=0; i<midterms.size(); i++) {
    sum += midterms.get(i);
}
double average=(sum/midterms.size());
System.out.print(average);
```